# Kubernetes setup on centos 7 hangs

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, centos

I have setup of 1 master and 2 salves of kubernetes on centos machines.

Also there is dashboard for kubernetes and 6 spring boot services. The mongodb is installed as service on master node.

The setup works fine for 1 or 2 days but then the system hangs and need to do the forceful restart. There are no memory or cpu panic logs or any kubernetes error logs available. The CPU and memory usage is 2% of total available.

Please can anyone suggest any issues with the setup. Below is the versions that i use:

**Docker**  - `Docker version 1.13.1, build 64e9980/1.13.1`

**CentOS** -

````
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"```


**Kubernetes** - 
```kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.4", GitCommit:"c96aede7b5205121079932896c4ad89bb93260af", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-17T11:39:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}```

**mongodb** -
v4.0.19
````

Comment: share kubectl get nodes output , could you please elaborate "system hangs" , is it the applications that hang or is it the nodes or which component ?

Comment: The system hangs means, i can not ssh to it or it does not reply to any commands. The os hangs. nodes it gives one error "The nodes stopped sending status'. Then kubectl get nodes gives error - The connection to the server <host>:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
i have to manually restart the machine.

Comment: You're using new version of K8s but old version of docker. I can`t find any info if the this version is validated in 1.18 but can you try to update your docker to version 18?